# Import NPM module having dependency

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm

Currently switching to Meteor 1.3 and his npm module support, I've got this issue:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'tip' of undefined
```

Here the related code **myFile.js**:

```
import d3 from 'd3';
import d3tip from 'd3-tip';

//...
chart.tip = d3tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
         //...
      });
```

The error come from the package `d3-tip`:

```
(function (root, factory) {                                                                                            
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {                                                                    
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module with d3 as a dependency.                                                   
    define(['d3'], factory)                                                                                            
  } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {                                                           
    // CommonJS                                                                                                        
    module.exports = function(d3) {                                                                                    
      d3.tip = factory(d3)  // HERE THE ERROR (d3 probably not defined)                                                                                           
      return d3.tip                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                  
  } else {                                                                                                             
    // Browser global.                                                                                                 
    root.d3.tip = factory(root.d3)                                                                                     
  }                                                                                                                    
}(this, function (d3) { //...}
```

I guess the package `d3-tip` don't find `d3`, but `d3` as `d3-tip` are finded on `myFile.js`.

Should I do something to manually inject d3 on d3-tooltip?

Comment: How is your package.json file? d3-tip should be stated as a dependency there and you must run `npm install` as well

Comment: @VitorRigoni d3-tip is a dependency and it is installed, cause my app can access to the d3-tip code since the error is coming from code into d3-tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you actually have to do

```
import d3tip from 'd3-tip';
d3tip(d3);
```

to get it to attach to d3.tip()

Answer (score 1):

Had an issue with this failing:

`import d3 from "d3";`

This was the solution:

`import * as d3 from "d3";`

I hope it will help someone.